# Python adding dictionary values from separate script runs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary I generated within a script:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
```

The script to generate the dictionary will be run many times over different files to generate more dictionaries, each within their own script:

```
dict2 = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c':2}
dict3 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c':0}
```

My plan was to add these to a file individually, then add values with the same key (e.g. one entry for 'a': 8) once the file has been appended with all dictionaries.

Is there a way to add the values of the dictionaries as they're added to the file? Or some other way to do this that results in the values being added as each script completes?

Edit: I'm new to coding, please explain slowly and clearly if you can. :)

Comment: What's wrong with just having a single `dict0` and calling for example `dict0['a'] += some_value` for all files?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) may help?

Comment: Are these files run in parallel? Is there a master program that runs them? You could write data to a single file if this program is only run serially, or to multiple files otherwise (`tempfile.mkstemp` may help with that). A heavier lift but good in your environment is `couchdb` or `mongodb` with map-reduce jobs to keep track of current values.

Comment: Julien - I should've mentioned I'm new to coding. I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to add new generated dictionary values to a pre-existing file.

For example, dict 1 would be already in the file. I did this with

```
with open(file.txt, "w") as f:
        for i in dict.keys():
            f.write(i + " " + str(dict[i]) + "\n")
```

To add dict 2, dict 3, etc into the file: 
I took the file.txt that had dict1 and re-wrote it into a dictionary with

```
for line in f:
            values = line.split(sep)
            dict[values[0]] = int(values[1])
```

Then I added the two dictionaries within the program and re-wrote the new dictionary back out to the file.

Probably not the most elegant answer, but it works!